# Swift compiler crash - anyone seen this?

Tags: swift, crash, switch-statement, option-type

I have an Obj-C class extending `NSObject`.  One of its properties is an `NS_ENUM`; let's call it `direction`.

Then I have a Swift class with an optional property of this Obj-C class; let's call that `message`.

The following example code is fine:

```
switch message?.direction
{
case .Inbound:
    ...
case .OutBound:
    ...
case nil:
    ...
}
```

However, if I then introduce:

```
guard let message = self.message else { return }
```

and remove the `?` in the code above, the compiler crashes; see below.

It seems to get confused by `case nil:`, because the crash disappears if I delete it; it's of course no longer needed.

Just curious, has anyone seen this Swift compiler crash?

```
1.  Apple Swift version 5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29)
2.  While emitting IR SIL function "@$s7SomeFunction...".
 for 'update()' (at /Users/.../SomeFile.swift:83:11)
0  swift                    0x00000001133554ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000113354cc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6b8d75fd _sigtramp + 29
3  swift                    0x000000010f1aaa4c (anonymous namespace)::SinglePayloadEnumImplStrategy::consume(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::irgen::Explosion&, swift::irgen::Atomicity) const + 1244
4  swift                    0x00000001131d082c llvm::IRBuilderBase::CreateLifetimeEnd(llvm::Value*, llvm::ConstantInt*) + 28
5  swift                    0x000000010f2105a1 swift::irgen::FixedTypeInfo::deallocateStack(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::irgen::StackAddress, swift::SILType) const + 81
6  swift                    0x000000010f2e8244 swift::SILInstructionVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction, void>::visit(swift::SILInstruction*) + 33828
7  swift                    0x000000010f2dc8e3 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 8835
8  swift                    0x000000010f190032 swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 1410
9  swift                    0x000000010f2baed9 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::StringRef, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, llvm::GlobalVariable**) + 1097
10 swift                    0x000000010f0b236f performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, bool, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, bool, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 4255
11 swift                    0x000000010f0a77c0 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 48416
12 swift                    0x000000010f01f4d3 main + 1283
13 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6b6decc9 start + 1
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'SomeApp' from project 'SomeApp')
```

Comment: Any crash of that sort should be reported to bugs.swift.org. There's nothing we can do for you here.

Comment: FWIW, I was unable to manifest the crash in Xcode 11.4 (ObjC `Message`, a `NS_ENUM` for `Direction`, a Swift `switch` on `direction` property, `case nil`, etc.). There must be some salient detail that is missing from the above or something unique to your configuration. I’ve gotten the rare compile crash which is almost always fixed with emptying of derived data and restarting Xcode. Regardless, I’d suggest creating blank project, and see what you need to do in order to reproduce the problem. And if you find a reproducible scenario in the latest Xcode/Swift, then go ahead and file a bug report.

Comment: @Rob I did delete derived data and started Xcode. Thanks for testing this out. I was already afraid that it might be related to other details. Hopefully someone from the Swift team sees this and picks it up.

Comment: I feel your pain, but until you can identify how to reliably reproduce this in a new blank project, they’ll be hard pressed to be able to do anything with this.